# id = nil, when sending data from R to postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, postgresql

Let's say I have a model users, with attributes: name:string, email:string.  If I create a user online or in the console and save that user, the user is given an id.  However, if I send (via R) user data into my posgresql database, the users will have attributes but no user id.  What do I need to do to ensure users will have an id, when I'm importing data to the model?

**Rails Console User Id Check**

```
2.2.1 :002 > User.first.id
  User Load (12.6ms)  SELECT  "Users".* FROM "Users" LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

**R import code**

```
  require("RPostgreSQL")

  pw <- {
    "password"
  }

  con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "my_database_production",
                   host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                   user = "user_name", password = pw)

  dbExistsTable(con, "users")

  dbWriteTable(con, "users", 
               value = new_data, overwrite=TRUE)

  dbDisconnect(con)
  rm(pw)
```

Comment: Are you just talking about row numbers that got automatically added?

Comment: are row numbers attribute ids?  I don't think so.  the attribute id is assigned to each new model instance.

Comment: What are you talking about when you say "model instance"? You might want to include some sample data for each step (what it looks like in R, in psql, and in Rails). This question is very unclear.

Comment: Are both your apps using R? Can you do a selective data-dump from the db that the R-app is using... then reimport using standard postgres commands (ie bypass rails)?

Comment: sorry, if I'm not being clear.  If I have a model, User, and there are ten users, what I mean by model instance is user 1, user 2, etc..  Each user is assigned an id, so that user 1 = user.id.1, user 2 = user.id.2, etc.  When I send my data from R to postgres, none of my users have an id.

Comment: hi Taryn East, thanks for your response, and that's probably where I'll go next -- the psql commands.  But before I went there, wanted to see if there was a way to send from R to psql and keep model ids.  Also, I only have one app. I'm just using R to sanitize the data before sending it to psql.  The only 'app' I have is the rails app.

Comment: Hack-R and Taryn, I updated my question and hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure I've got this right: you want to add users, and have the action return the new user ids so you've got some way of referring to them, presumably later in the function.

I don't know whether there's a built-in function to do this in Rails already, but if the R app needs to know the user ids of new users, you can either do this as:

1) a two-step: insert, then `select id from Users where [blah]`. Using `dbWriteTable()` doesn't quite do this: the existing users table gets over-written when you write the new table in. I'm assuming`id` is a `serial` type or is from a server-side sequence, i.e. assigned by the database.

2) Use an insert query with the `RETURNING` clause. Caveat: I'm not a Rails expert, so there might be other table-magic we need to do.

```
require(DBI) # for dbQuoteString()

users <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
  name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Claire"),
  email=c("alice@foo.com", "bob@bar.com", "cc@baz.com")
  )

# protect against names that have quotes, like O'Toole.
# and protect against SQL injection at the same time.
# If we had any integer or float values, protect against
# sqli like this: 
# num_val <- as.numeric(num_val)
# int_val <- as.integer(int_val)
users$name <- dbQuoteString(ANSI(), users$name)
users$email <- dbQuoteString(ANSI(), users$email)

qry <- "INSERT INTO Users (name, email) VALUES "

# now build the "values" string.
vals <- apply(users,1,paste,collapse=",")
vals <- paste("(",vals,")", collapse=", ")

qry <- paste(qry, vals)

# in this example, we return all the columns we've inserted,
# plus the user id.
qry <- paste(qry, "RETURNING name, email, id")

res <- dbGetQuery(con, qry)
```